# Python - Receiving "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'" when testing code in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to build a vaccine tracker for my apartment complex. When I'm trying to test the below code in jupyter-notebook I receive following error when I use non integer inputs.

Ask: What's the best solution to resolve this error? I'm a complete beginner in python and trying to learn and practice at the same time.

Error:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
2 print("2.Covaxin")
3
----> 4 vaccine_type = int(input("Select a number - "))
5 if vaccine_type ==1:
6   covishieldData

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'

Code:

```
print("1.Covishield")
print("2.Covaxin")
    
vaccine_type = int(input("Select a number - "))
if vaccine_type ==1:
  covishieldData
elif vaccine_type ==2:
  covaxinData
else: 
  print("Invalid Input - Please enter either 1 or 2 to proceed further")
```

Comment: Did you put `a` when you are prompt to input for `Select a number - `?

Comment: Yes. As it's user input anyone can accidentally put a or b or any special characters. I want to ensure (Validation loop for every wrong input, till user selects the correct input). Once the correct input is selected then move to next function

Answer (score 1):

You will need an error checking for your input before passing the input into the next steps.

A common practice is to use a loop with try-except to wrap the prompt until the input is valid.

```
while True:
    try:    
        vaccine_type = int(input("Select a number - "))
        if vaccine_type != 1 and vaccine_type != 2:
            raise ValueError
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid Input - Please enter either 1 or 2 to proceed further")
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read a bit documentation before you use any functions. If you are not aware of what a function is, read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp).

The error or exception(not normal behaviour) which you are getting is because while passing input to in-built **[input](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_input.asp)** function, you are passing the character **a**, then the in-built function **[int](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-int-function/#:%7E:text=int()%20function%20in%20Python%20and%20Python3%20converts,in%20given%20base%20to%20decimal.&text=string%20%3A%20consists%20of%201%27s%20and,string%20in%20the%20given%20base.)** tries to convert this string **a** to integer with base 10. Since **a** is not a valid integer, hence the python interpreter throws this exception/error.

Please use checks as **burringalc** recommended in other answer and make sure it could be converted to a valid integer or make sure you only pass input as **1** or **2**, since you only wish to check for 1 or 2 as an input.